# File Not Found Error while Downloading Image files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, error-handling, python-requests

I am using Windows 8.1, so I have been web scraping a lot recently and have been very successful in finding out some errors as well, but now I am stuck in downloading the files as they will not download and giving me a

> FileNotFoundError.

I have removed all the unknown characters from the name files but still, get this error. any help.

I have also made the names lowercase just in case. The error happens when I download the 22nd item, other items download fine before the 22nd one .

My Code and also the Excel file For reference:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests

Final1 = pd.read_excel("Sneakers.xlsx")
Final1.index+=1

a = Final1.index.tolist()
Images = Final1["Images"].tolist()
Name = Final1["Name"].str.lower().tolist()
Brand = Final1["Brand"].str.lower().tolist()

s = requests.Session()

for i,n,b,l in zip(a,Name,Brand,Images):
    r = s.get(l).content
    with open("Images//" + f"{i}-{n}-{b}.jpg","wb") as f:
        f.write(r)
```

Excel File (Google Drive) : [Excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tAZ1ceX42Ee_7XBLbi_PiA0FVRM4qRRb/view)

Comment: Are you using Windows? If yes then you are likely to need a backslash not a forward slash change `with open("Images//" + f"{i}-{n}-{b}.jpg","wb") as f:` to `with open("Images\\" + f"{i}-{n}-{b}.jpg","wb") as f:`

Comment: hi i tried it but still getting same error                                                                                                  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Images\\22-textured spotted port upper new design collector edition stylish luxury casual running partywear basketball shoes top quality sports sneakers for boys sneakers for men-crownprince.jpg

Comment: the error happens when i download the 22nd item other items download fine before the 22nd one

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems like you don't have `Images` folder in your path.
2. It's better way to use `os.path.join()` function for joining path in python.

Try Below:

```py
import os
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests

Final1 = pd.read_excel("Sneakers.xlsx")
Final1.index+=1

a = Final1.index.tolist()
Images = Final1["Images"].tolist()
Name = Final1["Name"].str.lower().tolist()
Brand = Final1["Brand"].str.lower().tolist()

# Added
if not os.path.exists("Images"):
    os.mkdir("Images")

s = requests.Session()
for i,n,b,l in zip(a,Name,Brand,Images):
    r = s.get(l).content
    # with open("Images//" + f"{i}-{n}-{b}.jpg","wb") as f:
    with open(os.path.join("Images", f"{i}-{n}-{b}.jpg"),"wb") as f:
        f.write(r)
```

Comment: hi i tried this also.. i still get the same error :( the error happens when it gets to the 22nd image the previous 1-21 download fine

Comment: Can you please let me know what the error message is? Because when I tried, it works fine for the very last file(160-combo(r)-628-995 sneakers for men-swiggy.jpg)

Comment: hi, i just deleted that particular entry which was causing problems. that's all i guess